# ERC725 with ERC735 - Identity and Claims

Tags: solidity, identity, erc725, erc735, nft

How does ERC725 (Identity) and ERC735 (Claims) work together to enable a decentralized identity?

Answer (score 2):

The identity consists of two main parts: Keys that owns and controls the identity and Claims that belong to that identity.

### ERC725: Identity Keys

Is used to manage unique identity for humans, groups, objects, and machines.
This identity can hold keys to sign actions (transactions, documents, logins, access, etc), and claims, which are attested from third parties (issuers) and self-attested ([#ERC735](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/735)), as well as a proxy function,  to act directly on the blockchain.

### ERC735: Identity Claims

It describes standard functions for adding, removing and holding of claims. These claims can be attested from third parties (issuers) or self-attested.
This standardized claim holder interface will allow Dapps and smart contracts to check the claims about a claim holder. Trust is here transferred to the issuers of claims.

### The relation between ERC725 and ERC735

ERC 735 deals with the management of claims made about an ERC 725 identity. It facilitates an emergence of a web of trust, by relying on the claims of trusted third parties about a given identity.

The following is the inheritance diagram showing how the standards could be implemented. Note that the 'final' identity smart contract inherits both functionalities of ERC 725 and ERC 735:

```
+---------------+     +---------------+
|               |     |               |
|    ERC 725    |     |    ERC 735    |
|               |     |               |
+-------+-------+     +-------+-------+
        ^                     ^
        |                     |
+-------+-------+             |
|               |             |
|  Keys Holder  |             |
|               |             |
+-------+-------+             |
        ^                     |
        |                     |
        |             +-------+-------+ 
        |             |               |
        +-------------+ Claims Holder |
                      |               |
                      +-------+-------+
                              ^
                              |
                              |
                      +-------+-------+ 
                      |               |
                      |   Identity    |
                      |               |
                      +---------------+
```

---

Reference:

https://hackernoon.com/first-impressions-with-erc-725-and-erc-735-identity-and-claims-4a87ff2509c9

You can check a good code that uses both ERC725 (used for Identities) and ERC735 (used for Claims):
https://github.com/OriginProtocol/origin-playground/tree/master/contracts

Answer (score 0):

> In the physical world, we prove our identity with documents like a
>   driver's license. These documents assert facts about us such as our
>   name, age, or eye color. But driver's licenses don’t exist on the
>   Internet. Instead, to prove our identity we’re forced to use a
>   patchwork of username-password systems.
>
> Because we deal with so many of these soiled systems, often on a daily
>   basis, our personal information ends up being replicated and sold all
>   across the Internet, compromising our privacy and undermining our
>   security.

**For reference yo can check here:**

https://hackernoon.com/first-impressions-with-erc-725-and-erc-735-identity-and-claims-4a87ff2509c9